# excel 2007 MS Query

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, query

I have created a spread sheet using MS query. I have added several columns to the rows of data so there can be some manually entered notes at the end of each row. The problem is when I refresh the data all of the manually entered data is lost. What am I missing?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but if you've linked your sheet with an external source, Excel only read the data, the data you enter in Excel cannot be written back to the database. It goes only one way. There are two ways to go around it: use Access or change your table for a list and add a column with a vlookup toward another sheet containing the manual comments.